# Compare two version strings in PHP

Tags: php

How to compare two strings in version format? such that:

```
version_compare("2.5.1",  "2.5.2") => -1 (smaller)
version_compare("2.5.2",  "2.5.2") =>  0 (equal)
version_compare("2.5.5",  "2.5.2") =>  1 (bigger)
version_compare("2.5.11", "2.5.2") =>  1 (bigger, eleven is bigger than two)
```

Comment: Probably *"natural order"*, have you tried http://php.net/strnatcmp ?

Comment: What's wrong with php's builtin [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)?

Comment: Test your code before you ask. I might just work (as in your case). -1 for that.

Comment: @hakre, sorry that I didn't realize there is actually a `version_compare` function in PHP ... and `strnatcmp` also works.

Comment: @ohho: Yes, that is exactly the issue. Do your homework ;) I remove the negative vote now after you've seen this. And serach the manual, just add it after the domain name: http://php.net/version_compare - you can't have a first look easier.

Comment: @hakre, my fault. I googled all around `strcmp`, but... It's my fault.

Comment: Yes sometimes it's not seeing the woods for the trees. It's somehow ironic that you choosed the right function in your question without seeing that ;)

Comment: Before using `version_compare` function please 
`Note that pre-release versions, such as 5.3.0-dev, are considered lower than their final release counterparts (like 5.3.0).`
and 
`Special version strings such as alpha and beta are case sensitive. Version strings from arbitrary sources that do not adhere to the PHP standard may need to be lowercased via strtolower() before calling version_compare().`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the PHP interactive prompt using the [`version_compare`](http://php.net/version_compare) function, built in to PHP since *4.1*:

```
php > print_r(version_compare("2.5.1",  "2.5.2")); // expect -1
-1
php > print_r(version_compare("2.5.2",  "2.5.2")); // expect 0
0
php > print_r(version_compare("2.5.5",  "2.5.2")); // expect 1
1
php > print_r(version_compare("2.5.11", "2.5.2")); // expect 1
1
```

It seems PHP already works as you expect.  If you are encountering different behavior, perhaps you should specify this.

Comment: Can confirm. Just works. ALL PHP versions. http://3v4l.org/U0mvm#v430 Same for the natural order compare.

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can use the PHP built-in function as below by passing an extra argument to the `version_compare()`

```
if(version_compare('2.5.2', '2.5.1', '>')) {
 print "First arg is greater than second arg";
}
```

Please see [version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) for further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/composer/semver.

comparison example:

```php
use Composer\Semver\Comparator;

Comparator::greaterThan('1.25.0', '1.24.0'); // 1.25.0 > 1.24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version compare doesnt work, the code below will produce your results.

```
function new_version_compare($s1,$s2){
    $sa1 = explode(".",$s1);
    $sa2 = explode(".",$s2);
    if(($sa2[2]-$sa1[2])<0)
        return 1;
    if(($sa2[2]-$sa1[2])==0)
        return 0;
    if(($sa2[2]-$sa1[2])>0)
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: [`function new_new_version_compare($a, $b){ return explode(".", $a) <=> explode(".", $b); }`](https://3v4l.org/XL7t8) ...but there's absolutely no reason to engineer a replacement for a perfectly suitable native function like `version_compare()`.