# PHP usort by ascending array value

Tags: php

Below is partial of my array

I tried to use the function below to sort it to order by page ascending
However it seems rumble around, the page are not in increment state.

I not sure what's wrong with my sorting comparator function (cmp)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['page'] - $b['page'];
}


usort($chapter_result_array,"cmp");
$chapter_result_array = array_reverse($chapter_result_array);



[11] => Array
    (
        [link] => https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/funny-story/chapter-8-1.1046/
        [page] => 8.1
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [link] => https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/funny-story/chapter-8-2.1085/
        [page] => 8.2
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [link] => https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/funny-story/chapter-9-1.1114/
        [page] => 9.1
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [link] => https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/funny-story/chapter-6-1.890/
        [page] => 6.1
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [link] => https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/funny-story/chapter-6-2.995/
        [page] => 6.2
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [link] => https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/funny-story/chapter-7-1.1020/
        [page] => 7.1
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [link] => https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/funny-story/chapter-5-1.855/
        [page] => 5.1
    )
```

Comment: not sure, what you want. Its better to give your desire output, so we can clear what you really want.

Comment: Note that the manual says that "The comparison function must return ***an integer*** less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

Comment: @Gralgrathor how do i make it work with "double"

Comment: Eh... something like "return ($a < $b) ? -1 : ($a > $b) ? 1 :  0;"? Or any rounding function, if you know what the range of your input is going to be.

Comment: Once you have it working if you follow @Gralgrathor's advice and you want them in reverse order you can swap `-1` with `1` in your function rather than call `array_reverse` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the pages are not `float` values but more like "version strings" so you should compare with version compare: [Compare two version strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067736/compare-two-version-strings-in-php)

It will return you -1, 0 or 1 like `usort` is intented to be used.